# Passing the data from one view to another SwiftUI via NavigationLink

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am building an iOS application using SwiftUI. I am a beginner to SwiftUI and Swift and Native IOS development. What I am trying to do now is that I am trying to pass data from one screen to another through NavigationLink. But the PreviewProvider of the destination provider is throwing an error.

I have the ContentView.swift with the following code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var listItems = [ BleDevice ]()
    init() {
        listItems.append(BleDevice(id: "ID 1", name: "Name 1"))
        listItems.append(BleDevice(id: "ID 2", name: "Name 2"))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack() {
                List{
                    ForEach(listItems) {
                        item in VStack() {
                            Text(item.id)
                            Text(item.name)
                            NavigationLink(destination: ServicesListView(device: item)) {
                                Text("Connect")
                                    .padding()
                                    .foregroundColor(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.blue/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                           Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }.navigationTitle("Devices")
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

As you can see I am trying to pass device object to the destination view. This is my ServicesListView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct ServicesListView: View {
    var device: BleDevice
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Hello, World!"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
    }
}

struct ServicesListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ServicesListView()
    }
}
```

But when I tried to compile the project, ServicesListView_Previews class is complaining, "Missing argument for parameter 'device' in call" as follow. I know that it is because it is not initialising the ServicesListView class with the parameter. But how can I pass the data to it too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For preview just pass static data like this

```
struct ServicesListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ServicesListView(device: BleDevice(id: "ID 1", name: "Name 1"))
    }
}
```

Comment: So it does not matter what value I pass from it? It will only pick up the data I pass from the previous view?

Comment: Yes. you need to pass static data for preview mode. Xcode does not take automatically from the list. If you runt the preview and run the app then it will take from the list.